# Remove space in print command for some specific values

Tags: python, printing

```
n=str(input("Enter your name"))
a=str(input("Where do you live?"))
print("Hello",n,"How is the weather at",a,"?")
```

How to Remove space between {a & ?} in the print statement?

Answer (score 2):

An [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) will give you better control over the exact formatting:

```
print(f"Hello {n}. How is the weather at {a}?")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Commas` in python add a space in the output.
No need to use `str` as inputs in python are already treated as strings.
You can use this:

```
n = input("Enter your name") 
a = input("Where do you live?")
print("Hello",n,"How is the weather at",a+"?")
```

This concatenates the two strings.

OR

```
n = input("Enter your name") 
a = input("Where do you live?")
print(f"Hello {n}! How is the weather at {a}?")
```

This is called [`f-strings`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/). It formats the string so you can put the value of a variable in the output.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply do it by using `end` inside the `print`**

**by default** its value is `\n` and if you set it an empty string `''`
it won't add anything(or any space).
after printing `a` and the `?` will print exactly after that.

*so you can write the code below:*

```py
print("Hello",n,"How is the weather at",a, end='')
print("?")
```

Comment: No need for these when there are simple ways.